# Html post is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, post

I am trying to make a simple website that posts information to an api and shows output as alert. But I can't get any alert.
Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <b>Enter name</b>
            <br>
                <input type="text" id="name">
            <br>
            <button id="button1">Submit</button>
            <script
             src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
            </script>
    <script>$('#button1').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://(api url)",
            data :{name:$('#name').value()},
        });
    });   
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `But I can't make it work` what exactly doesn't work? Does the request not get sent? Does the response not come back? Is the response wrong? Are you not sure how to process the response? Any errors in the console?

Comment: The name of the function is `val()` not `value()`

Comment: @vlaz I don't get any alert

Comment: To do anything with the response, you need to have a `success: fn()` in your ajax query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the result in alert, in that case you need to handle the success callback like following.

```
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "http://(api url)",
      data: {name:$('#name').val()}
      success: function(result) { alert(result) }
    });
```

> **success** **Type**: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR
>   ) A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets
>   passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted
>   according to the dataType parameter or the dataFilter callback
>   function, if specified; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR
>   (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery 1.5, the
>   success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will
>   be called in turn

Note that, `value()` is nothing in `jQuery`, you need to use `val()`

I suggest, along with success, you should also handle the error like following.

```
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     alert("Some error occurred");
  }
```

For more details on `$ajax`, I suggest you to go through the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is for a project and when I sent post with curl it gives an wrong name output in a txt file. But when I run this html code my alert is [Object object]. I am not very familiar with html and I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Instead of alert , use console.log, it will give you complete object

Answer (score 1):

You're very close, there are a few issues in your code. Your `data: {}` throws a syntax error since `.value()` doesn't exist it's instead `.val()` that you're looking for.

To display the results after a successful request to the API endpoint, you need to have a `success` callback which can be written as below. I am using a test dummy `POST` endpoint at the URL `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts` in the code below, replace it as needed with the actual URL you're requesting :

```js
$('#button1').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
        data :{name:$('#name').val()},
        success: function (data) {
         alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>Enter name</b>
<br>
    <input type="text" id="name">
<br>
<button id="button1">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is for a project and when I sent post with curl it gives an wrong name output in a txt file. But when I run this html code my alert is [Object object]. I am not very familiar with html and I don't understand the problem.

Comment: `[Object object]` means you're receiving an object as a response to the query you've made which might look like `{"name": "value"}` etc.., You need to access the key which contains the value you need to print. Use `console.log()` for debugging to see the entire object on your browser console.